# Getting lines between special char pattern

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

Below is my input file:

````
---
{
  "date":"2015-09-24",
  "title":"Getting Started with Git",
  "template":"post",
  "thumbnail":"content/thumbnails/test.jpeg",
  "slug":"getting-started-with-git",
  "categories":[ "cat1", "Focus", "Mustang" ],
  "tags":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ]
}
---

#Hello

---
This is sample
---

```
var x=1;
entry.forEach(function(item){
    x=x++;
})
```
````

What I am expecting in output is, lines between ***first*** 2 '**---**'

```
{
  "date":"2015-09-24",
  "title":"Getting Started with Git",
  "template":"post",
  "thumbnail":"content/thumbnails/test.jpeg",
  "slug":"getting-started-with-git",
  "categories":[ "cat1", "Focus", "Mustang" ],
  "tags":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ]
}
```

How can I achieve it? 
Using **awk**, I am able to achieve this only if i replace '**---**' with some string like 'start'/'end'.

```
awk '/start/{f=1;next} /end/{f=0;exit} f'  $FILE_PATH
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
awk '/^---/ {mark++; next} mark == 1 {print}' $FILE_PATH
```

Which produces:

```
{
  "date":"2015-09-24",
  "title":"Getting Started with Git",
  "template":"post",
  "thumbnail":"content/thumbnails/test.jpeg",
  "slug":"getting-started-with-git",
  "categories":[ "cat1", "Focus", "Mustang" ],
  "tags":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ]
}
```

This increments a variable named `mark` every time it encounters the `---` line. We only print lines when `mark == 1`. This is a nice solution because it will let you extract abitrary chunks of `---` separated text.  That is, if we wanted the *second* chunk of `---` delimited text, we could run:

```
awk '/^---/ {mark++; next} mark == 2 {print}' $FILE_PATH
```

Which gives us:

```
#Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an option, giving your example:

```
sed -n '/^{$/,/^}$/p' file
```

Output:

```
{
  "date":"2015-09-24",
  "title":"Getting Started with Git",
  "template":"post",
  "thumbnail":"content/thumbnails/test.jpeg",
  "slug":"getting-started-with-git",
  "categories":[ "cat1", "Focus", "Mustang" ],
  "tags":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ]
}
```

Comment: should probably be non-greedy.